# Как читать описатели в функции sprintf в PHP?

Tags: php

Привет.

Вопрос по PHP функции sprintf().
Почему

```
echo sprintf("%'.9d\n", 123);
echo sprintf("%'.09d\n", 123);
```

дает это

```
......123
000000123
```

?
Знак процента говорит "сейчас пойдет описатель".

`'.9d`  - это описатель.

`'.09d`  - тоже описатель.

**Как ПРОЧИТАТЬ эти описатели слева направо?**

Comment: Например, [википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf#.D0.A1.D1.82.D1.80.D1.83.D0.BA.D1.82.D1.83.D1.80.D0.B0_.D1.81.D0.BF.D0.B5.D1.86.D0.B8.D1.84.D0.B8.D0.BA.D0.B0.D1.82.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B0_.D1.84.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.BC.D0.B0.D1.82.D0.B0)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sprintf.php ?

Comment: я как раз оттуда (php.net/manual/ru/function.sprintf.php) пример и взял. этот пример дали и не объяснили

Comment: Как это "не объяснили"? Вся ссылка - подробное объяснение.

Answer (score 3):

В документация, параметр **format** имеет 6-ть пунктов, которые рассказывают как читать эти значения. Там много необязательных параметров, которые просто могут быть опущены, и вы их не увидите.

Конкретно в этом примере:

`'.9d`

- `'` - указывает какой за ним символ будет заполнять строку

> п.2 Необязательный описатель заполнения, который определяет, какой
>   символ будет использоваться для дополнения результата до необходимой
>   длины. Это может быть пробел или 0. По умолчанию используется пробел.
>   Альтернативный символ может быть указан с помощью одиночной кавычки
>   ('). См. примеры ниже.

- `.` - тот самый символ который будет заполнять строку
- `9` - длина строки

> п.4 Необязательное число, описатель ширины, определяющий минимальное
>   число символов, которое будет содержать результат этого
>   преобразования.

- `d` - аргумент трактуется как целое и выводится в виде десятичного числа со знаком.

---

`'.09d` - тут и для меня не все однозначно, кто может подробнее разжевать, буду признателен, ниже мои мысли, могут быть неверными.

- `'` - как и выше, указываем что следующий элемент будет заполнять строку до нужной длины.
- `.` - тот самый символ который будет заполнять строку
- `0` - и вот тут момент. Если вчитаться в п.2 - `Необязательный описатель заполнения ... Это может быть пробел или 0 ... Альтернативный символ может быть указан с помощью одиночной кавычки`. То есть вы или можете указать свой символ с помощью кавычки, как было выше с точкой - `'.`. Или просто написать `0` и он заполнить строку нулями. По этому так же будет работать - `echo sprintf("%09d\n", 123);`. Для меня только не ясно почему он игнорирует `'.` и выставляет нули, как бы перезаписываете настройки.
- `9` - длина строки
- `d` - аргумент трактуется как целое и выводится в виде десятичного числа со знаком.

Comment: наверно, на сайт php.net допустили ошибку с этим примером '.09d, потому что ноль после точки ни на какое правило не натянешь. спасибо за ответ

Comment: Скорее всего кто-то делал по принципу "если перед длиной стоит 0, то заполнять нулями". А теперь нужные 9 символов уже есть и точки ставить некуда. Сишный printf же пробелы и нули умеет, а вот кастомных заполнителей там нет.

Answer (score 1):

Тоже столкнулся с недопониманием в этом моменте. Заметил, что с пробелом в

`printf("%'. 9d\n", 123);`

отрабатывает как и с `"0"`

`printf("%'.09d\n", 123);`

соответственно заполняя для первого `" "`, для второго `"0"`. Вместо `"."` может быть любой однобайтовый символ. т.е. `printf("%'.09d\n", 123);` и `printf("%'@09d\n", 123);` выдают один и тот же результат.